# adding a list of menu items in a django session

Tags: python, django, session, menu

I have the user menu in an object list, and I want to put it into the django sesion. I've trying but django tells me

```
'list' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

actually this is the object that represents a item in the menu

```
class MenuItem(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, link, items=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.link = link
        self.items = items
```

and in a function I append MenuItems in a list.

```
menu = []
menu.append(MenuItem(1,
                     "hi",
                     "some_link"))
```

finally in the view I try to put the menu in session.

```
request.session['menu'] = menu
```

And in this part is when django throws a

> 'list' object has no attribute '_meta' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the object you're trying to store in the session is not serializable.

You can test with with

```
import json
json.dumps(MenuItem(1, "hi", "some_link"))
```

Which gives

```
MenuItem object at ... is not JSON serializable
```

One thing you can do is write your own function to serialize the object. Here's one way to approach it:

```
class MenuItem(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, link, items=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.link = link
        self.items = items

    def serialize(self):
        return self.__dict__
```

Then,

```
menu = []
menu.append(MenuItem(1, "hi", "some_link").serialize())
request.session["menu"] = menu
```