# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' error in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-sessions, django-cache

I'm trying to store a list of items in a Django session. The code is below,

```
def index(request):
  today = date.today()
  d = today.strftime("%A,  %B %d")
  if request.method == 'POST':
    item = request.POST.get('newItem')
    items = request.session.get('items',[])
    request.session.modified = True
    request.session['items'] = items.append(item)
  return render(request, 'todo/index.html', {'kindOfDay':d, 'newListItems': request.session.get('items', list())})
```

I get the following error, **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'**

I have included the below two lines in settings.py

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
```

I'm a beginner and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cant comment due to low reputation.
This is happening because `items` is an empty list therefore you cant append to it. Have you set a session with key 'items' anywhere in your code before trying to get it?

This is how you set a session with key 'items':

```
request.session['items'] = 'item1'
```

And this is how you get it:

```
request.session.get('items')
```

see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) for more on django sessions

Comment: I want the session with key ```items``` to store a python list. Is it possible to store a list?

Comment: Yes it is. But how is that related to this question? You are getting session 'items' which is non existent and put it inside `items`. assuming `items` is not empty, you try to append something to it and that's why you're getting error.

Comment: If you need help with storing a list as session value please see other SO questions.[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621174/adding-a-list-of-menu-items-in-a-django-session) might help you.

Comment: Doing as you said ```request.session['items']``` will reset the cookie every time the site is opened. I want the browser to save the cookies

Comment: Then that's another question and not relevant to this one. please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47093904/13913033).If you still have issues please consider asking a separate question.

Comment: Where should I place ```request.session['items']```? If it's inside the same function then the session key is overwritten every time a request is made to that made.

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve in your program. But generally, you set session in one place and then use it elsewhere. That's the whole point of session I guess??

Comment: Again If I am not understanding your question raise a new issue with more details. Maybe someone else can help you.